# Expected value of threshold function

Tags: probability, integration

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f(x)$, $\alpha>0$ a constant and $g(x)$ a function with $g(x)=\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{c}
g_{0},\\
g_{1}
\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}
if & x<z\\
if & x\geq z
\end{array}\end{cases}$, where $z$, $g_{0}$ and $g_{0}$ are some (finite) constants.

Is the following correct?

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)^{\alpha}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{z}g_{0}{}^{\alpha}f(x)dx+\int_{z}^{+\infty}g_{1}{}^{\alpha}f(x)dx=Pr(x<z)\times g_{0}{}^{\alpha}+Pr(x\geq z)\times g_{1}{}^{\alpha}$

Thanks in advance,

Frank.

Comment: Yes. You are welcome.

Comment: Yes, and it is equal to $E[g(X)^\alpha]$ but I guess you knew that.